# Как добавить Json данные в jade?

Tags: json, gulp, jade

Суть вопроса в том как передать объект данных в jade
для примера

`data.json`

```
{
  "menu" : [
      {
        "title" : "title",
         "href" :  "href"
      }
    ]
}
```

и просто вызвать в jade

```
each val in menu
    a(href=val.href)= val.title
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{ "menu" : [ 
    { "title" : "title", "href" : "href" } 
   ] 
 }
```

gulp ...

.pipe(data(function() 
{ 
  return require('./app/data/data.json'); 
}))

...

each val in menu

Answer (score 0):

Сначала удалите пробелы функцией JSON.stringify(), потом объявите переменную

`- var menu = [1,2,3]
each val in menu
    a(href=val.href)= val.title`

**UPDATE**:
В файлах Jade может содержаться не только JSON, но и полноценный Javascript. Чтобы строка была истолкована как код, она должна начинаться с дефиса и пробелов

Comment: спасибо за ответ.,
но у меня никак не находит объект
надо чтобы данные  с файла json брать

Comment: это я все понимаю и делаю вроде правильно но почемуто невидит переменной объекта
{
  "menu" : [
      {
        "title" : "title",
         "href" :  "href"
      }
    ]
}


gulp 
...
 .pipe(data(function() {
            return require('./app/data/data.json');
        }))
...
each val in menu

Comment: Перенесите этот код в вопрос и отформатируйте его